Tailwind config for package being used in multiple apps
As a part of my organization's design system, I have a package called "core" from which I am exporting all the CSS. The apps have it as a dependency and it gets installed as a node_module in their application.
I recently added tailwindcss to my "core" package but tailwind classes won't apply to applications using my package since they cannot specify the content path.
module.exports = {
  content: [], -> This resides in my "core" package and apps cannot modify it
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};

One option I have is to use safelist property in the tailwind.config.js file and add all the CSS that I need but I don't want to do that. I want to have a way where the end application can use any tailwind class they want to and also benefit from the JIT compiler/purge feature of tailwind, so that their bundle doesn't include all the tailwind CSS.
How can the applications using my package specify the content path dynamically?
PS - I am using rollup if that makes any difference.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

The solution I implemented for a similar issue was to expose the tailwind configuration in my library, along with multiple functions (such as mergeConfig(customConfig))
Once the config file is exposed, it can then be used by your apps to declare their own tailwind configuration, but that implies that each app should have tailwind installed.
The other approach would be to expose your final, compiled styles, instead of the ones that need to be compiled by tailwind.

I understand that we can export a function from tailwind.config.js in the core package instead of an object. But how will this be exported over to the other packages?

Before being a configuration file for tailwind, this is just a Javascript file that is ran by NodeJS when tailwind has to create the CSS files. That means you can just export it like you would do with any other JS file.

Ah, I get your approach now. Your consumer application has tailwind installed and you're just merging the two configs in the consume application's tailwind.config.js, right?
My requirement is that the consumer application shouldn't have to install the tailwind since they have used my "core" package which provides them with tailwind. I hope you get my point.

You got the approach, and I get your point. That's my second approach, where you need to compile your styles and ship them with your app : unless you install tailwind on the consumers, you have no way of compiling them, so this is the only viable solution. Another very cumbersome solution could be to make a binary to compile the files on the consumer side, but that's just extra steps for the same result ...

Your last point seems interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Not really because I haven't done it, but to give you an example, when one uses Angular, one can type npx ng generate component my/component : this is a binary, that you can find in your node_modules/.bin directory : your goal would be to replicate this behavior, so that the user can type npx yourlib compile-css (or something similar), and it would compile the Tailwind CSS to regular CSS. But then again, it's just more (complicated) steps from the previous approach, which is to just directly ship your compiled CSS !

Thanks bud! I am going to go with your original solution to merge the config in the consumer application. Thanks for your time to help me out :)
